# Regex in swtoolbox router

Tags: browser-cache, service-worker, sw-toolbox

I've been trying to use the [swtoolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox) for service worker. There is the case i want to use the url pattern matching to make network only and cache only.

i'm still stuck to make it work.

Basic usage is working fine.

```js
toolbox.router.get('/index.html', () => new Response('Test'));
```

When i started using the Regex. It's not working as expected.

```js
toolbox.router.get('/.*(\.html$)/', () => new Response('Test'));
```

It would be nice if anyone tried doing that make it work. I had use to validate my Regex is working fine first there. https://regex101.com/

Comment: Why the `/` at the end of your regex?

Comment: Don't we start and end when with slash for Regex ?

Answer (score 0):

found out that it assume as the string. I've to remove the single quote to run as the Regex.

```js
toolbox.router.get(/.*(\.html$)/, () => new Response('Test'));
```